# Passing a pointer to a member function as argument for a void* function

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have the following function:

```
void PerformAction(void(*pf_action)());
```

and the following class:

```
class A
{
public:
    void DoSomething();
}
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    PerformAction(&(a.DoSomething);

    return 0;
}
```

I have seen many answers that say that the function signature should be:

void PerformAction(void(A::*)());

**This is not what I want.**

I want to able to pass it any function/method that receives no parameters and returns void. Not just member methods of A or just global functions.

Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Why not use `std::function<void ()>` as the parameter type?

Comment: member methods are different from free functions because they take an implicit `this` pointer as parameter, thus also a free function pointer is different from a member function pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to able to pass it any function/method that receives no parameters and returns void. Not just member methods of A or just global functions.
>
> Is this possible in C++?

Yes, it is possible, but you need to use a more flexible type. The way to achieve this is to specify the `PerformAction` function with a different type. You want to use a type that is callable with zero arguments and returns `void`, [`std::function<void ()>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). For example change the `PerformAction` function to be: `void PerformAction(std::function<void ()> fn);`. This version will allow you to accept anything that's callable with zero arguments and returns `void`, see the following code for an example.

#### Example Code

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    void bar() { std::cout << "Member function: Foo::bar()\n"; }
};

void bar()
{
    std::cout << "Free function: bar()\n";
}

class Functor
{
public:
    void operator()() { std::cout << "Functor object\n"; }
};

auto lambda = []() { std::cout << "Lambda expression\n"; };

void doSomething(std::function<void ()> fn)
{
    fn();
}

int main()
{
    doSomething(bar);
    doSomething(Functor());
    doSomething(lambda);
    
    Foo foo;
    doSomething(std::bind(&Foo::bar, &foo));
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/UX4ZeU)

#### Example Output

```
Free function: bar()
Functor object
Lambda expression
Member function: Foo::bar()
```

Comment: Doing `template <typename F> void PerformAction(F f)` is an other possibility which avoids the type erasure (but is less explicit than `std::function` for expected signature).

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I considered mentioning a templated solution but, as you stated, the `std::function` is much more explicit about the requirements. Are you recommending I update my answer to include the possibility of using a templated solution?

Comment: As you wish, now it is at least mentioned in comment.

Answer (score 2):

Plain function pointers and member function pointers are different things.

Member functions take a hidden `this` parameter, whereas plain functions do not. To call a member function through a pointer an object is required to initialize that `this` parameter.

Hence, you cannot convert a pointer to a non-static member function to a plain function pointer and call through it without passing in an object.